# Can I get the memory address on the data from the static JNI field?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, field, memory-address

Can I get the memory address on the data from the static JNI field?

For example, I have 2 situations:

First:

```
jclass clazz = ...;
jfieldID staticFiled = ...; // static field on java object
uintptr_t *staticFiledPtr = ((uint64_t) staticFiled); // get field ptr

jboolean *boolPtr = *magic code with static field*;
*boolPtr = true;
```

Second:

```
jclass clazz = ...;
jfieldID staticFiled = ...; // static field on java object
uintptr_t *staticFiledPtr = ((uint64_t) staticFiled); // get field ptr

jobject *objectPtr = *magic code with static field*;
jobject object = *objectPtr;
```

The examples are very simple. I just want to get the memory address on the static field data, without using GetStaticObjectField and etc. It is possible?

Comment: Directly poking into JVM-managed memory is a recipe for tears. Do not do this.

Comment: @Botje Sorry, I need this

Comment: Please explain why you use case is so special it needs to break the JVM memory safety and why the Get\*Field methods are not sufficient.

Comment: you can look at the openjdk implementation, find the offset of jclass to the underlying "oop" (might be 0). Then the fieldID is just an offset: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/9583e3657e43cc1c6f2101a64534564db2a9bd84/src/hotspot/share/oops/oop.inline.hpp#L200 . This will obviously be thread-unsafe and only work for specific implementations of the jdk. (it will also only work if the static field is from that class exactly and not inherited from another class, otherwise you have to manually search the parent class objects)

Comment: @Botje I just need this. I'm sorry, I can't tell you why I need this.

Comment: @PeterT Using experiments, I noticed that the address of the static change and the address of the data I received using "GetStatic*Field" are shifted by the number of bytes that store the change. But changing the value of a change in address, the value in the java class does not change.

Comment: @Gru2303 if you just change the value from outside of java without jni APIs, but read the value from within java then the JVM will have no reason to re-read the static value from memory, because it will assume it's unchanged, right? That's why the JNI code does stuff like `oop_store_at` and check the thread

Comment: Why do you expect this object will remain in the same place in memory over time?  (One of many reasons why you should give up on this approach.)

Comment: @Gru2303 "*I just need this. I'm sorry, I can't tell you why I need this*" - then, I'm sorry, you are not likely to get much help on this. What you are asking for is borderline malicious, it breaks safeguards that are in place to protect memory and applications from abuse. So, if you have a *good* reason to break those safeguards, I suggest you explain it as best you can.

Comment: also, it appears like it's using "compressed pointers" on some architectures. So you can see that it "decodes pointers" https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/270cf67e5ff19b082f710d52831f436dd144d883/src/hotspot/cpu/x86/macroAssembler_x86.cpp#L5095-L5109 before writing/reading.  Some illustrations available here: https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-compressed-oops#1basic-optimization

Comment: @PeterT note that what you describe is an *implementation detail* of that particular JVM. No guarantee that other JVMs operate the same way. The returned ID of the static field is not guaranteed to be an offset at all.  Its value is meaningful only to the JVM's implementation of the `GetStatic<type>Field()` functions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am writing software protection against JNI and blocking the Set and Get Field function in some situations. And I need to get the memory address of the data field where it is stored

Comment: @Gru2303 *I am writing software protection against JNI...*  Do you control the JVM?  All the libraries the JVM links in? Can you protect against `LD_PRELOAD` or other library injections?  Do you control the OS and kernel the JVM is running under?  You need to really think your design through, else something you spend months or even years implementing might literally take someone who figures out what you're doing all of 30 seconds to defeat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fields in the JVM have no addresses. There are only references to objects (which are *not* pointers), and then those references are accessed at a certain offset to read or write a field.

This operation might involve un-compressing and adding the reference' value to the heap base address to obtain a temporary memory address. It will also potentially be guarded by GC barriers. i.e. it is not a simple pointer dereference. Of course, outside of this operation the GC is free to move the object around. Since every access is guarded by a GC barrier, even the reference value itself might be stale, since the GC could defer updating the value until just before the access, inside the GC barrier.

So, in short, getting the address of a field is not really possible, and reading/writing through that address even less so. At best you can hope to get some ephemeral value which points somewhere into the Java heap.