# thisObj in JNI function called from constructor refers to the class and not to the instance

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jniwrapper

I'm trying to implement a JNI library. I've noticed that thisObj passed to JNI function when called from a constructor differs from the same function called from a method.

Here is my minimal code:

```
public final class Test {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("jnitest");
    }

    private native void jni_test(int i);

    public Test() {
        jni_test(0);
    }

    public void m() {
        jni_test(1);
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
Test t = new Test();
t.m();
```

JNI side looks like this:

```
static void jni_test(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, int i) {
    printf("jni_test %i %p\n", i, thisObj);
}
```

The output is:

```
jni_test 0 0x7f3bb0288898
jni_test 1 0x7f3bb02888e0
```

As you see, thisObj is not the same. To be more precise, *thisObj* refers to the **Test class** when called from the constructor. And it refers to the **instance of the Test** when called from a method.

Why is this?

How to workaround it (except from explicitly passing *this* as one more parameter to the jni function)?

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? I'm allocating memory in C and subscribing to events from my library, so I need to make sure I can call back in Java with `this`.

Making a separate `.init()` call is not a nice idea since it makes the code heavier. Is it the only way to go?

Comment: @Jorn your explanation sounds the only reasonable. Still, with no confirmation by the doc and no explanation why is it a bad idea. But at least it points to the right way. If you turn it into an answer, I'll mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: The answer by @JornVernee sounds correct to me. I was assuming you were right when you said "thisObj refers to the Test class when called from the constructor. And it refers to the instance of the Test when called from a method.", which is apparently not true. So that invalidates my theory.

Comment: @Jorn Indeed, I got the issue. I was checking the handle returned back from Java and it was referring to the class - but that was a pure chance I got it - I was saving a local reference instead of the global one. After switching to global everything went ok. It was a pure chance that the local handler pointed to something reasonable in the callback and matched the class object. So the clue was to globalize the reference before saving it! Thanks to Jorn and Jorn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you see, thisObj is not the same. To be more precise, thisObj refers to the Test class when called from the constructor. And it refers to the instance of the Test when called from a method.
>
> Why is this?

You are incorrect in your theory. What you're printing out in the C code is an object handle, not the `this` pointer. Pointers to java objects are not exposed directly to native code. This wouldn't work as the garbage collector can move the objects around, even at the same time that the native code is executed.

Instead the VM will allocate an object handle, which can be thought of as a token that indirectly refers to the Java object, and only the GC knows how to access correctly (which is encapsulated by the JNI api). Across multiple calls, this means that the value of the handle can change, because a new handle is created for every call.

But in both cases, the handle will refer to the `this` object. This has nothing to do with the place from where the method is called. Because `jni_test` is an instance method, it requires a receiver argument. Both of the calls to `jni_test(...)` in your Java code, are just short for `this.jni_test(...)`. And that `this` is what the `thisObj` handle refers to in the native code.

This is also explained in the [JNI specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/jni/design.html#native-method-arguments):

> The JNI interface pointer is the first argument to native methods. The
> JNI interface pointer is of type JNIEnv. The second argument differs
> depending on whether the native method is static or nonstatic. The
> second argument to a nonstatic native method is a reference to the
> object. The second argument to a static native method is a reference
> to its Java class.

The `jni_test` method is not `static`, so the second argument refers to the object.

> How to workaround it (except from explicitly passing this as one more parameter to the jni function)?

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, or what kind of workaround you're looking for. Rest assured though, that there's no way to expose a stable native address pointing at an arbitrary Java object.

Comment: See also my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72778943/3699139

Comment: The C library I use can call back a function to notify me about events. I save the global handle to this object in my code and pass it to the library (together with the VM handle), so when the lib calls me back in the handler sitting in JNI part, I can use it to call the corresponding method of an instance of a Java object. This is why I need "this" handle

Comment: Your answer does not answer the questions. I know the reference is just a handle, and I know this is a short for of this.jni_test(...). But thisObj in the call from the constructor is not the class instance object, but the class object, which is not obvious. This was the question... The comment to the question is the answering on it, but still with no official doc.

Comment: The clue was to do `jobject self = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, thisObj);` before saving it.

Answer (score 1):

You declared your method as `private native void jni_test(int i);`, which means the corresponding C signature is:

```
void Java_<package>_jni_1test(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint i);
```

regardless of where it is called from, with `obj` being *an instance of class Test*.
You can safely pass `obj` to other methods or call methods on `obj`, but the same caveats on doing stuff inside constructors apply.

The other answer already explained why your test is testing the wrong thing so I will not repeat it.

EDIT: I wrote the following code to disprove your statement:
Added the following main method to Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Test t = new Test();
  t.m();
}
```

and the following inside the jni_test method:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_jni_1test(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint i) {
    jclass cls_Test = env->FindClass("Test");
    printf("Inside call with i=%d\n", i);
    printf("\tobj instanceOf Test: %d\n", env->IsInstanceOf(obj, cls_Test));
    printf("\tobj.getClass() == Test: %d\n", env->IsSameObject(cls_Test, env->GetObjectClass(obj)));

    jmethodID mid_Test_toString = env->GetMethodID(cls_Test, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring str = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(obj, mid_Test_toString);
    const char * str_output = env->GetStringUTFChars(str, nullptr);
    printf("\tobj.toString(): %s\n", str_output);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str, str_output);
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
Inside call with i=0
    obj instanceOf Test: 1
    obj.getClass() == Test: 1
    obj.toString(): Test@1eb44e46
Inside call with i=1
    obj instanceOf Test: 1
    obj.getClass() == Test: 1
    obj.toString(): Test@1eb44e46
```

This conclusively proves that yes, even within a constructor, `this` refers to the object being constructed. I do not know how you arrived at a different conclusion, but I can only assume your test code is faulty somehow.

Comment: Sorry, this explains nothing. `obj` does not refer to a local handle of and instance of class Test if this function is called from the constructor, while it is if called from any other method. I got the idea why is could be done that way, but I believe the explanation is an attempt to explain why could it be. I've not found any official doc stating this and explaining it. I understand that the workaround is to ask the user to call some method after "new Test()", but it is not a nice way to do it.

Comment: Can you explain how you determined that "obj does not refer to a local handle of and instance of class Test if this function is called from the constructor"?

Comment: I call `(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, thisObj, methodID)` and do `System.out.println(this)` in that function.

Comment: And what method do you call? What is the output?

Comment: If called from the constructor, it is Test (the class) and if from a method, it is Test@23454 (an instance of Test calss)

Comment: See edit. I cannot reproduce your findings at all.

Comment: The clue was to do jobject self = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, thisObj); before saving it. Indeed, everything is working

Comment: You cannot possibly expect us to have guessed that the actual problem was you reusing local references across jni invocations...

Comment: Agree, sorry for the unclear question